# Remove some characters from a string by index (Raku)

Tags: raku

FAQ: In Raku, how do you remove some characters from a string, based on their index?

Say I want to remove indices 1 to 3 and 8

```
xxx("0123456789", (1..3, 8).flat);  # 045679
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Variant of Shnipersons answer:

```
my $a='0123456789';
with $a {$_=.comb[(^* ∖ (1..3, 8).flat).keys.sort].join};
say $a;
```

In one line:

```
say '0123456789'.comb[(^* ∖ (1..3, 8).flat).keys.sort].join;
```

or called by a function:

```
sub remove($str, $a) {
    $str.comb[(^* ∖ $a.flat).keys.sort].join;
}

say '0123456789'.&remove: (1..3, 8);
```

or with augmentation of Str:

```
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class Str {
    method remove($a) {
        $.comb[(^* ∖ $a.flat).keys.sort].join;
    }
};

say '0123456789'.remove: (1..3, 8);
```

Comment: That solves the problem completely in my opinion. Thanks for reminding that \ and (-) are equivalent. I don't see other ways to [slice](https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#Slices) with the index I __don't__ want and not the indices I want.

Comment: You don't have to use `MONKET-TYPING` if you just make it free floating method and call it as `'foobar'.&remove: (1..2, 4);`  (augment can have problems with composition if used several times)

Comment: (which isn't to say augment is bad, just that the `.&remove` is a way to remove that.

Comment: I added the non-augmentation variant as to your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Probably combining chenyfs pairs and noelem with map would be even more elegant - no sorting required: .comb.pairs.map({.value if .key ∉ (1..3, 8).flat}).join ?

Comment: I could shorten away (0 .. .chars -1) away with just the Whatever ^*

Comment: ∖ confusing and seems like a backslash character.

Comment: Yeah, looks much like a backslash, but is not. But it is the usual character for a difference of sets, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Definition

Answer (score 12):

```
.value.print if .key  !(elem) (1,2,3,8) for '0123456789'.comb.pairs
```

Answer (score 9):

My latest idea for a not-at operation (I'll cover the implementation below):

Usage:

```
say '0123456789'[- 1..3, 8 ]; # 045679
```

Implementation, wrapping (a variant of) Brad's solution:

```
multi postcircumfix:<[- ]> (|args) { remove |args }

sub remove( Str:D $str is copy, +@exdices){
    for @exdices.reverse {
        when Int   { $str.substr-rw($_,1) = '' }
        when Range { $str.substr-rw($_  ) = '' }
    }
    $str
}

say '0123456789'[- 1..3, 8 ]; # 045679
```

The syntax to use the operator I've declared is `string[- list-of-indices-to-be-subtracted ]`, i.e. using familiar `[...]` notation, but with a string on the left and an additional minus after the opening `[` to indicate that the subscript contents are a list of *exdices* rather than *indices*.

*[Edit: I've replaced my original implementation with Brad's. That's probably wrong-headed because, as Brad notes, his solution "assumes that the [exdices] are in order from lowest to highest, and there is no overlap.", and while his doesn't promise otherwise, using `[- ... ]` is awfully close to doing so. So if this syntax sugar were to be used by someone, they should probably not use Brad's solution. Perhaps there is a way to eliminate the assumption Brad's makes.]*

I like this syntax but am aware that Larry deliberately did *not* build in use of `[...]` to index strings so perhaps my syntax here is inappropriate for widespread adoption. Perhaps it would be better if some different bracketing characters were used. But I think use of a simple postcircumfix syntax is nice.

(I've also tried to implement a straight `[ ... ]` variant for indexing strings in exactly the same way as for `Positional`s but have failed to get it to work for reasons beyond me tonight. Weirdly `[+ ... ]` will work to do exdices but not to do indices; that makes no sense to me at all! Anyhow, I'll post what I have and consider this answer complete.)

---

*[Edit: The above solution has two aspects that should be seen as distinct. First, a user-defined operator, the syntactic sugar provided by the `postcircumfix:<[- ]> (Str ...`, declaration. Second, the body of that declaration. In the above I've used (a variant of) Brad's solution. My original answer is below.]*

---

<strike>Because your question boils down to removing some indices of a `.comb`, and re`join`ing the result, your question is essentially a duplicate of ...</strike> *[Edit: Wrong, per Brad's answer.]*

[What is a quick way to de-select array or list elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568766/perl6-what-is-a-quick-way-to-de-select-array-or-list-elements) adds yet more solutions for the [`.comb ... .join`] answers here.

---

Implemented as two multis so the same syntax can be used with `Positional`s:

```
multi postcircumfix:<[- ]> (Str $_, *@exdex) { .comb[- @exdex ].join }

multi postcircumfix:<[- ]> (@pos,   *@exdex) { sort keys ^@pos (-) @exdex } 

say '0123456789'[- 1..3, 8 ]; # 045679

say (0..9)[- 1..3, 8 ];       # (0 4 5 6 7 9)
```

The `sort keys ^@pos (-) @exdices` implementation is just a slightly simplified version of @Sebastian's answer. I haven't benchmarked it against jnthn's solution from the earlier answer I linked above but if that's faster then it can be swapped in instead. *[Edit: Obviously it should instead be *Brad's* solution for the string variant.]*

Comment: "I think use of a simple postcircumfix syntax is nice". Definitely ! I love this solution: super clear to read.

Comment: I've always felt that "negative" (or "negative-appearing") indices are inherently problematic.

Comment: @jubilatious1 If someone doesn't like `-`, they could pick a different character/string that signifies "exclude these". Perhaps `[except ...]`? Brevity was the soul of this answer, so I'd be happier with `[not ...]`. More generally, such things are somewhat subjective. Note .@Tinmarino's reaction. To be clear, the `-` isn't "negative" in a numeric addition/subtraction sense, but in the regex character class sense -- `<-[abc]>`, i.e. "exclude these". It's only "negative-appearing" in the sense it's `-`, a character, like it is in "negative-appearing". In the latter, it's understood as "hyphen".

Comment: Hello @raiph! Yes, agreed on what you said. My hope was to **stimulate** discussion on what those non-negative, non-hypen looking characters might be. Tossing out random ideas here...something like  `⊣`
(LEFT TACK, Unicode: U+22A3) ?? Of course, this could conflict with a  pre-existing meaning... .

Comment: @jubilatious1 Please join me in [a chat room I just made for this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237429/except-these).

Comment: @raiph @Sebastian Sorry for the lack of clarity in my last message. If I call the Raku one-liner `raku -e '"0123456789".elems.put;'` at the bash command line, I get the result `1`. The string `0123456789` is one element. Conceptually it's difficult to understand how a postfix `[ … ]` can make any meaningful change to a object with only one (`1`) element.

Answer (score 9):

Everyone is either turning the string into a list using `comb` or using a flat list of indices.

There is no reason to do either of those things

```raku
sub remove( Str:D $str is copy, +@indices ){
    for @indices.reverse {
        when Int   { $str.substr-rw($_,1) = '' }
        when Range { $str.substr-rw($_  ) = '' }
    }
    $str
}

remove("0123456789",  1..3, 8 );  # 045679
remove("0123456789", [1..3, 8]);  # 045679
```

The above assumes that the indices are in order from lowest to highest, and there is no overlap.

Comment: This is the fastest answer by a factor of 150 on my machine (with `my $s = "0123456789" x 1000; my $l = (1..3, 8, 40, 100, 1001, 4000..4100).flat`). Comb is long for long strings Thanks @BradGilbert, this will definitely help some people, at least me :-)

Comment: @Tinmarino That is because MoarVM doesn't usually copy strings, instead it creates substring objects that point into the original string. When you use `.comb` it has to create many of those objects, and combine them back together. With `substr` it creates as few of those objects as possible.

Comment: "substring objects that point into the original string" : is that why it was decided to implement Str as immutable ? Impressive optimization anyway.

Answer (score 8):

yet another variants:

```
print $_[1] if $_[0] !(elem) (1,2,3,8) for ^Inf Z 0..9;

.print for ((0..9) (-) (1,2,3,8)).keys;
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the closest I got in terms of simplicity and shortness.

```
say '0123456789'.comb[ |(3..6), |(8..*) ].join
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my $string='0123456789';
for (1..3, 8).flat.reverse { $string.substr-rw($_, 1) = '' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old-ish question, but here's another version that takes a similar approach to Brad Gilbert's `substr-rw` solution but avoids needing to edit the string in-place (and thus fits better with a functional-programming mindset):

```raku
sub remove(Str:D $str, +@indices) {
    ($str, |@indices.reverse).reduce: -> $_, $idx {
       { S/.**{$idx.head} <(.**{$idx.elems})> .*// }}
}


say remove "0123456789", 1..3, 8;    # OUTPUT: «045679»
say remove "0123456789", [1..3, 8];  # OUTPUT: «045679»
```

This is not *that* different from the `substr-rw` solution when both are wrapped up in a function.  But the version above lends itself to better inline use, at least imo:

```raku
say S/.**5 <(.**3)> .*// with "0123456789"; # OUTPUT: «0123489»
```

instead of

```raku
say do with "0123456789" -> $_ is copy { .substr-rw(5..7) = ''; $_ } # OUTPUT: «0123489»
```

Note, however, that the `S///`-based approach isn't any faster than the `.comb` approaches so using `.substr-rw` could be useful in performance-critical areas.