# What's an elegant way to return a list without the nth element?

Tags: raku

What is an elegant and efficient way to return a list without the nth element?
I'm now using something like:

```
my @b = @a;
@b.splice($n,1);
return @b;
```

but that's not very elegant, and probably not efficient either.

(Something like `return @b.spliced($n,1)` would be nicer, but that doesn't work.)

```
return flat @a[0..^$n,$n^..*]
```

isn't much better.

Comment: I would like to see an ```.isplice``` method (immutable splice) so you can go ``` @a.isplice($n,1)``` and it will return the result leaving @a unchanged.

Comment: @p6steve, that's what I tried to suggest with `@b.spliced($n,1)`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any other way other than the ones you described.

I have been thinking about expanding the `.skip` method to multiple parameters, which would allow for `@b.skip($n,1)`.

EDIT: this is now a [Pull Request](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/5008)

EDIT: this has now been merged and will be in the 2022.08 release

Comment: Thanks, @elizabeth, that will certainly do the trick.  Still, a method `spliced` which returns the spliced array while leaving the original unchanged, would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about elegant or efficient, but another solution is this:

```
@a.grep: { $++ ≠ $n }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not built in, assumes exdices are already in sorted order and don't overlap, may not be optimizable, not type checked, but at least "sugared" -- though whether it's natural or artificial, whether it's healthy or rots your gut, is a matter of taste:

```
multi postcircumfix:<[- ]> (|args) { remove |args }

sub remove( @arg is copy, +@exdices){
  for @exdices .reverse {
    when Int   { @arg .splice: $_,   1 }
    when Range { @arg .splice: .min, +$_ }
  }
  @arg
}
```

Use like this for example:

```
say (0,1,2,3,4,5)[- 1..2, 4]; # [0 3 5]
```

This "solution" is an array variant of [my answer to "Remove some characters from a string by index"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60878454/1077672), with the caveats mentioned in both this answer and the earlier one.